# Discover devices which have app installed

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Without connecting to the other devices, please suggest/tell how can I discover devices which have my app installed. I don't want to register MAC address, IMEI numbers in my database, so please suggest some other way.

Comment: I've the similar requirement. I want my device discoverable/searchable by other device which has my app installed in it without connecting. Did you find any solution?